# GLSL link info log in chinese

Tags: java, opengl, logging, glsl, shader

I was testing glsl and shader wasn't doing what I want. I have this piece of code to retrieve logs (I'm using JOGL).

```
gl.glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, INFO_LOG_SIZE, charsWritten, bb);
```

I get the string from within "bb" and find marvelous question marks.
I debug and then I find this
[image: Chinese PWNING me]

In my infinite knowledge of chinese google tells me:

> Garrulous contravene several ⁳ radial Tangju Shuiceonliedao Aigeshexiong ⁣ Lake Yanjishuolang ⁲ Mu ⁯ Quraomangshui Fang

As you can see this is very helpful to me :D

Can I change the log language... or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're intrepreting some random binary data as a string; Windows internally uses wide characters (i.e. 16 bit chars) so any data being nonzero in the high byte will end up rendering some asian script.

**EDIT: (It's a Java program, didn't notice that first)**
Java's ByteBuffer asCharBuffer interprets the data in the buffer as wide character string (i.e. two bytes per character), while OpenGL will return you a one byte per character string. I'm not a Java wizard, so I'd probably produce a lot of Coded Smorgasbrod if I attempted a solution here. You need to find a function that properly converts a 8 bit per character string into a Java CharBuffer, or manually prepend each returned byte with a zero byte.

Comment: Hey pal, this is Java and bb is a ByteBuffer perfectly initialized.

Comment: And here it is more: I have 2 log retrieval for shaders and 1 log retrieval for the program and every single log has different length :/

Comment: You are right man, i created a byte[] with the chars 'w','o','t', passed the bytes to a ByteBuffer and the output of CharBuffer was '?' Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The log output is not produced by OpenGL, it is produced by the shader itself. I assume you didn't write the shader, so whoever did wrote the log messages in Chinese.

There are two possibilities: Either the shader actually was written with logs in Chinese, and I don't know why they are trying to tell you about garrulous contravention, or (judging by the fact that there are empty box characters in there), it actually isn't Chinese, just some random byte output and there is a bug in the shader.

Either way, the problem is in the shader, not in some setting with OpenGL.

Comment: Those shaders are 1 line test shaders of mine. I just was messing with attributes and stuff.First has main and gl_Position = gl_ProjectionMatrix * gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;

Comment: Oh. Well then I was wrong, and I don't know what the problem could be. :| Sorry!

Comment: Vertex has main and gl_Position = gl_ProjectionMatrix * gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex; Fragment has main and gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.6,1.0,1.0); I test the link status of shaders and opengl tells me there's something wrong and that message appears when I read the logs.